# editing DNS rules locally in macOS 10.12

Tags: network, macos, dns, hosts

When I develop web sites I like to have them run locally and responding to a more useful name than localhost/site. It used to be you could write rules in hosts pointing to 127.0.0.1. It would seem you can't any more, as when I add a rule like `127.0.0.1 Site` typing "site" in the address window of the browser won't resolve to 127.0.0.1.

Is there a way to get the hosts file settings respected or is there another method I can use instead?

Comment: Thanks. You're right. When I ping my sitename in hosts I get the local IP. However, it would seem browsers, Firefox and Safari in this case, first go to the internet for consulting and ignore what the OS thinks. So I end up on the net somewhere instead of on my local server. Maybe I need to change my network settings in the browsers?

Comment: I tried to flush the DNS cache with `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`, but that didn't help. Both Safari and Firefox still get out on the net.

Comment: Please add your web server software (including whether it's OS X Client/Server)|config and your hosts file **to your question**! You may obfuscate the host names but if you've set up several different sites use something like host1/2 // sld1/2 // tld1/2.

Comment: Are you running native version of Apache which is pre installed or are using something else like Bitnami? I am running Sierra with no problems using my ip, localhost, 127.0.0.1 and and a generic DNS. Also, are you using a router and are the correct port open and pointing to your local ip..

Comment: I was running MAMP (Apache + MySQL), but because I needed this time also get a self-signed certificate going I installed MAMP Pro trial which worked on the hosts file itself.

It wrote `127.0.0.1       website.com 
::1       website.com  ` and now Firefox doesn't go onto the net. I forgot what ::1 means, but I think it's IPv6 related.

Comment: @norcaljohnny, I don't see how router settings would affect anything. 127.0.0.1 kinda guarantees no traffic would be going out.

Comment: Are you editing the /etc/hosts file? Because I just tried this and it works perfectly in Safari and Chrome with no changes to the DNS cache. Make sure you're using complete domain names like sitename.com rather than sitename because Safari will just ignore what you actually typed even if you did it as http://test/ it will end up at test.com.

Comment: @ToddDabney, see above comment. Catering for IPv6 helped.

Comment: @MiB nice catch, didn't think about the sites that are moving to IPv6